# ADOTable locate current datetime from database

Tags: delphi

I am just learning Delphi so please have patience with me. :)
I have an Access database field `'DATE'` which is of `DateTime` type.
It stores date and time.
I dropped a timer on my form and  in `on timer` Event :

```
`if ADOTable1.Locate('date',now) then showmessage('Date and Time Found!);`
```

But I am getting :

> 'not enough actual parameters' error.

Where am I 
messing up?

Another thing I am curious about: If you set the timer to do a locate every minute will it miss the actual time if it searches for seconds too? Is there way I can eliminate seconds from the datetime search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for TADOTable.Locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Locate) requires three parameters:

```
function TCustomADOTable.Locate(const KeyFields: string; const KeyValues: Variant;  
  Options: TLocateOptions): Boolean;
```

You're passing two. Your call should be

```
if ADOTable1.Locate('Date', Now, []) then
```

What goes in `Options` depends on whether you're searching on an index or not, whether you're doing a case-sensitive search or not, or none or both of the above.